# Dealing with upper limits when fitting data

Tags: regression, modeling, error, fitting, curve-fitting

Let's assume that I have a set of data composed by two measurements, X and Y (plus respective errors), and I am interested in studying their linear correlation, i.e., finding a linear best-fit Y = a*X + b and the relative scatter around such a model.
However, for a sub-set of my values (concentrated into the low-Y region, although this may be irrelevant) I do not have robust measurements of Y (due to instrumental limits) but only upper limits (chosen to be at 3 sigma of the gaussian distribution of noise for each point). 
An important constrain is that Y cannot be negative.

Is there any way of "taking into account" those upper limits when fitting a function to the data?
In other words, what is the best approach to see if these limits on "non-measured" points (i.e., for which I could not get a measurement) are "statistically relevant", and for instance could significantly affect the best-fit?

Comment: Please provide a clearer description of "upper limit:" exactly how is it determined? *Eg,* if you simply add $3\sigma$ to all measurements, then subtracting $3\sigma$ from them all eliminates the problem.  I suspect you might be dealing with detectability issues--but I there are well over 20 different statistical definitions of a limit of detection or quantitation, so you need to be specific. Also, please search our site for [censoring](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=censor*%20detect*), because it's likely some of those posts apply to your situation, whatever it might be.

Comment: Our sigma is computed as the rms of the noise, centred on zero and Gaussian distributed. In case of non-detections we do not have any measurement to add 3 sigma to; we can only estimate a limit, which depends on the sensitivity of the instrument.

Comment: That's too vague, though.  How do you estimate the noise?  How do you determine what is a nondetect?  Could you perhaps supply a small worked example in the body of your post?

Comment: Thank you for asking. It helps in defining the problem. 
Our noise is very robustly estimated, and in principle it could be analytically derived (therefore no uncertainties on it). We determine what is non-detected setting a threshold of 3.5 sigma (Signal / Noise) assigned by models.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you determine a value of $\sigma$ *a priori* and then declare any result to be undetected when the instrument reads less than $3.5\sigma$? If that's the case, then [see these hits](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=censor*+detect*+regression+-logistic).

Comment: Yes this is the case. Then, for non-detected points (i.e. when the instruments read less than 3.5 sigma), I decide to use the 3 sigma value as a "upper limit" of this measurement. Therefore at the end I will have some measurements for detections and upper limits for non-detections, and here comes my question.
I will check your link.

Comment: How to answer this question depends on what you mean by "how they correlate:" it could be the calculation of a correlation coefficient, a linear regression of X on Y, a linear regression of Y and X, or something more complex (such as nonlinear regressions or calibrations). Perhaps you could edit your post to explain what you mean.  Regardless, it's generally a poor idea to replace the nondetects by any constant value for analyses unless the relative range of the true underlying value is small (but then you probably wouldn't even be worrying about this issue).

Comment: Edited. Basically I want to fit a linear model to the data.
In particular I do find that detections are well represented by a linear fit Y = a*X + b with a reasonable scatter, and I would like to know if non-detections are consistent with this fit, or considering them would imply an inadequacy of the linear model.